# Initial value problem-Picard's conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

This is a true or false test:

For b) I don't understand how to find if a differential equation satisfies Picard's conditions or not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (c): if $x(t)=0$ for all $t$, then $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ for all $t$. Hence, for all $t$,
$$
0=\frac{dx}{dt}=2tx(t)^{2/3}=2t \cdot 0^{2/3}=0.
$$

For (b), I guess that you are asked if the function $(t,x) \mapsto 2tx^{2/3}$ is locally Lipschitz in the $x$-variable, but it is just my guess.

Comment: And that there are two solutions for the initial value problem already tells the story on (b).